# Is it possible to use ConfigParser to get random value

Tags: python, parsing, random, configparser

I want to get a random value from .ini file in the range of 14, 55. I know I'm doing it wrong but what is the right way?

```
import random
import configparser

IN_settings = configparser.ConfigParser()
IN_settings.read('config.ini')

print(IN_settings['common'].getint((random.randint('out_put')))
```

and this is my config file:

```
[common]
out_put = 14, 55
```

Comment: This needs multiple steps: Reading the setting as string, parsing it as two integer numbers (mainly cutting in two strings and converting each to an int) and retrieving a random int in the given range. Try to write the code for each step. If you have a specific issue with this you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

The `random.randint()` function does not take a string as an argument. It takes two integers as arguments.

So, when you say `random.randint('out_put')`, the function does not work. `'out_put'` is a string, not two integers.

You will need to read in the actual integers first.
Of course, the field `out_put` is not a single integer, but rather two integers. We'll have to read it as a string, and then convert it.

```
range_str = IN_settings['common'].get('out_put')
range_ints = [int(x) for x in range_str.split(',')]
random_int = random.randint(range_ints[0], range_ints[1])
print(random_int)
```

That works. For your example file, this will print a random integer in the interval [14, 55] (including the end points).